# Where can I find soap?

Tags: west-of-loathing

In the initial town of Boring Springs you can trade soap for a lock, which you need because someone callously misplaced another one.

But, where is the soap? I figure'd it'd be in the Gang's Hideout near the tub but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was watching a [Markiplier video](https://youtu.be/iVWOZ8ctPE0?t=22m45s) of this game, and inside the Fricker Gang's hideout, one of them is bathing in a bath tub and appears to be taking a nap. If you approach the guy in the tub and talk to him, one of your options is "Pssst. Can you pass the soap?"  After selecting this option, you will be given a bar of soap.

I'm assuming if you chose a choice that involved killing the guy in the tub, or letting the Sherf take him, you won't be able to get the soap from him.

Answer (score 0):

Wandering Sally also has a bar of soap for sale in her shop, if you didn't get the one inside Fricker's Gang hideout. If you wander around a bit by going to different places on the map, you usually can run into her and buy stuff from her.